# Using Excel DSUM with logical OR

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have the following DB and problem:

[image]

But I need

```
"Either A=1 OR c=1"  => **should yield 26**
```

How can I achive it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your criteria on 2 separate rows for logical OR in database formulas like DSUM.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That was what I needed.